# How do I completely reset Samba to the shipped defaults?

Tags: samba

Since [no one can help me with sharing files from Samba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19361/cant-access-ubuntus-shared-folders-from-windows-7), how can I reset it to the defaults and delete any residual configurations from previous releases?  Then, presumably, the GUI sharing would work after I reinstall samba.  I tried using dpkg reconfigure samba, but it made things even worse, and now my ubuntu computer's hostname stopped existing.  >:(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common
sudo rm -rf /etc/samba/ /etc/default/samba
sudo apt-get install samba
```

If you still have problems please provide more details.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  I removed samba-common, too.  Not sure if that was necessary, though.

Comment: You do indeed need to purge and reinstall samba-common aswell just samba is not enough