# Ubuntu shared folders using samba not getting listed in windows 7

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows-7, samba

I am trying to share files using samba from my Ubuntu 14.04 machine to Windows 7 machine which are connected to the same network . I have set up samba in my ubuntu machine, gave sharing permissions to the folders and modified the smb.conf file as stated by this thread [Can't access Ubuntu's shared folders from Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19361/cant-access-ubuntus-shared-folders-from-windows-7/19379#19379). But what I find is that shared folders are not getting listed under networks of my ubuntu machine in my Windows 7 machine

Below is the lines I have added in smb.conf for the shared folders

```
[Personal$]
   comment = Personal
   path = /home/local/aarish/Personal
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   available = yes

[Movies$]
   comment = Movies
   path = /home/local/aarish/Movies
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   available = yes
```

Can someone please tell me how do I fix this issue and get the sharing from ubuntu to windows machine successful ?

Comment: That's not how it works. You have to connect to the computer first by typing `\\ubuntu-computer-name` in Explorer. You'll see your shared folders here.

Comment: @Zacharee1 My ubuntu machine is listed under Network of my windows machine but it is just not listing the shared folders!! What should I do ?

Comment: Did you restart samba?

Comment: `sudo service samba restart`

Comment: @Zacharee1 Ya I did. I have tried everything whatever I was able to find out for troubleshooting but in vain!!

Comment: Maybe take the `$` away

Comment: @Zacharee1 It worked!! Thanks a lot. Please post this as answer so that I can upvote

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because of that `$` in the share names. Remove that and you should be good.