# What password am I supposed to type when accessing a shared folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: samba, shared-folders

- Installed Ubuntu 16.04.1. Let's say the name of the Ubuntu is `amc`
- I logged into Ubuntu. Let's say the account name is `walking` and the password is `dead`.
- On Nautilus, I selected a directory in my home folder, and chose Local Network Share.
- It asked me if I wanted to install required things, and I clicked OK.
- In the share option of the directory, I checked "Share this folder" and "Allow others...", but did not check on "Guest...".
- I did not do any terminal `vi` config things, as the GUI seemed to work.
- I restarted Ubuntu.

From Windows, I opened File Explorer and typed `\\amc`. It showed the shared directory. When I double-clicked it, File Explorer showed a network credential pop-up. I typed `walking` in the user name, and `dead` in the password, and clicked OK. But it showed "Access is denied". Then I typed `amc\walking` in the user name instead, but it still showed "Access is denied".

What user name and password am I supposed to type? Isn't working on GUI enough? Should I also do some manual config editing?

---Added---

The linked post and answers are 6-year old, and did not work.
`sudo restart smbd` failed with `connection refused` or something. The `gksudo` showed administrator password dialogue, to which I typed my user account password, and it failed saying the password was wrong.

Another answer proposed `system-config-samba`. I installed it but it failed to start saying something like `/etc/libuser.conf no such file`.

Comment: Looks like you did everything right. You may want to change permission of the public (shared) folder as shown in step 2 of [Windows-Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201#310201) part of the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access Ubuntu's shared folders from Windows 7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19361/cant-access-ubuntus-shared-folders-from-windows-7)

Comment: Their symptoms were similar but the proposed answers did not work. And some of the commands and programmes seemed to be outdated, and showed errors on my 16.04. Moreover, my smb.conf messed up and I deleted the /etc/samba and tried to remove with `--purge` and reinstall it with `--reinstall`. Now samba cannot be even installed with `Errors were encountered while processing : samba`. This was kind of my experiment of "Is Ubuntu's UI mature enough so that I can do this one simple task without furiously searching Google and typing and editing complicated config files?" And it failed.

Comment: PS: If I checked "Guess access", then I could access the shared directory. Without that guess access, accessing the directory showed access error both from Windows (File Explorere) or another Ubuntu 16.04 (Nautilus).